# math expression in latex

Tags: math-mode

In fact, I don't know how to write this expression on LaTeX:

[image]

And thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have a problem writing the braces? What is exactly your problem? Can you show us the compilable code you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes problem with braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage[thin, , thinc]{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\[
\dot\sigma = \diffp{\sigma}{{\mathbf x}}\overbrace{\dot{\mathbf x}}^{\diff{\mathbf x}{t}}\bigl(\mkern1.5mu\overbrace{f(\mathbf x, t) + B(t, \mathbf x)\mathbf u}^{\dot{\mathbf x}}\mkern1.5mu \bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]